# Notation in regards to inequality

Tags: inequality

Give the inequality $y \cdot (f(x,y))$ $\ge 0$, I obtain that (0,0) satisfies this (this I can see from the function, my questions are only notation-related).

I then assume that $y \ge 0$ and solve $f(x,y) \ge 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(x) \ge y$, and then conclude that $0 \le y \le f(x)$.

Is this correct notation,in regards to the $\ge$ signs and so on (I'm thinking maye I should assume $y > 0$, as I already showed it for $y=0$), and the method in general? In the conclusion, I still have $x$ as an unknown variable, don't I need to say what this is limited to as well? How do I do that?

May sound very simple, but my teacher takes of many points for even  small problems with notation.

Answer (score 0):

You are headed in the right direction. You can divide both sides of the inequality by $y$ if you attach the additional condition "$y>0$" to the resulting inequality, since this excludes the case $y=0$ (in which case the division is not permitted) and the case $y<0$ (in which case the inequality no longer holds since the reverse inequality holds instead).

It may be easier to consider the three cases separately, as follows. I am assuming here that there are no domain considerations to worry about (you can consider those yourself, since you aren't telling us what $f$ is).

**Case 1:** Assume $y=0$. Then the inequality reduces to $0\geq 0$, which is true for all values of $x$. The solutions here are all pairs $(x,0)$.

**Case 2:** Assume $y>0$. Then after dividing by $y$, the inequality reduces to $f(x,y)\geq 0$. You can now look for solutions to this inequality. They will be of the form $(x,y)$ where $y$ is a positive number.

**Case 3:** Assume $y<0$. Then after dividing by $y$, the inequality reduces to $f(x,y)\leq 0$ (it reverses because of the division by a negative number). You can now look for solutions to this inequality. They will be of the form $(x,y)$ where $y$ is a negative number.